# Should i built a new theme or modify the existing theme in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want my webpage in Wordpress to have a header, a field next to header,left and right column and footer.There are theme in wordpress that have header,right column and footer but not left column which I need it for my ads.So,should I built a new theme or modify an existing theme to get the desired design.What is the least possible time consuming way of doing it?

Comment: well you can easily add sidebar in wordpress or can create.

Comment: Ok you mean adding side bar in the existing theme,don't you?

Comment: yes..you just have to change little bit html and css or go with widget..

Answer (score 1):

Make a new one,

You'll loose more time NOW, but you'll learn how to do and you'll be able to edit faster in the future.

There're thousands of guides out there
https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20create%20a%20new%20wordpress%20theme

Comment: Ok,you mean I should make a new one although it will be time consuming but,it will be helpful in the future and modifying an existing theme will be less time consuming for now.

Comment: Yes, but also you wont get stuck with any structure that you don't like, If you want a thing done well, do it yourself.

Comment: Of course you don't need to build anything from scratch, you can use any front-end framework you like as well.. Bootstrap, YUI...

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress there are you can use any existing theme. most possibilty you use twently fifteen. it is nearly all file that we have needed. it take less time and you are not need to again write your functions.